# structure of msg in IPC message queues

Tags: c, linux, chat, message-queue

I am having some trouble while using a custom definition of message struct in message queues. I am building a chat app between a client and a server. The client is sending a message, while the server is receiving the msg and printing it.

This is the server side code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX 200
#define SERVER 1L

typedef struct {
    long    gid;
    char    buffer[MAX];
    char    header[20];
    long    pid;
} MESSAGE;

struct msqid_ds buf;
MESSAGE msg;
int mid_server, mid_client;
key_t key1, key2;
int client_id = 0;

int main(){
    //Creating a message queue
    key1 = ftok(".", 'z');
    msg.gid = 1;
    if((mid_server = msgget(key1, IPC_CREAT | 0666))<0){           
        printf("Error Creating Message Queue\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //Receiving message from client, throws and error if input is invalid
        if(msgrcv(mid_server, &msg, MAX, SERVER, 0)<0){
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(-1);
        }  
    //Server displays received message
        printf("SERVER receives: %s\n", msg.buffer);
        printf("SERVER receives---: %s\n", msg.header);
        printf("SERVER receives: %ld\n", msg.pid);                            
}
```

This is the client side -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 200
#define SERVER 1L

typedef struct {
    long    gid;
    char    buffer[MAX];
    char    header[20];
    long    pid;
} MESSAGE;


int mid_client, mid_server;
key_t key1,key2;
MESSAGE msg;
int client_id = -1;

int main(){
    //Creating a message queue
    key1 = ftok(".", 'z');
    if((mid_server = msgget(key1, IPC_CREAT | 0666))<0){             //server receives here
        printf("Error Creating Message Queue\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("%d\n", mid_server);
    fgets(msg.buffer, MAX, stdin);
    msg.gid = SERVER;
    strcpy(msg.header, "msg");
    msg.pid = 2;
    if(msgsnd(mid_server, (struct MESSAGE*)&msg, sizeof(msg), IPC_NOWAIT)==-1){
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("message sent\n");  
}
```

My doubt is that it prints the msg.buffer data on server side alright, but fails to print anything for msg.header and prints 0 for msg.pid. Is this issue because of the structure of MESSAGE. Also, is the "size_t msgsz" parameter in msgsnd correct? TIA

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd), the `msgsz` parameter is the size of the message buffer minus the `mtype`. So using `sizeof(msg)` is not correct, it will cause `msgsnd()` to read beyond the end of the variable `msg`. Also, it will cause the server to fail, since the server only expects to receive `MAX` bytes (again, excluding `mtype`).

I would avoid adding multiple member variables to `struct msgbuf`, and instead just add one member that is either a `char` array big enough to hold whatever data you want to send, or another `struct`. For example:

```
#define MAX 200
#define SERVER 1L

struct payload {
    char    buffer[MAX];
    char    header[20];
    long    pid;
};

struct msgbuf {
    long gid;
    struct payload payload;
};
```

And then you can use it like so in the client:

```
struct msgbuf msg;

msg.gid = SERVER;
fgets(msg.payload.buffer, sizeof msg.payload.buffer, stdin);
strncpy(msg.payload.header, sizeof msg.payload.header, "msg");
msg.payload.pid = 2;

if (msgsnd(mid_server, &msg, sizeof msg.payload, IPC_NOWAIT) == -1) ...
```

And like so in the server:

```
struct msgbuf msg;

if (msgrcv(mid_server, &msg, sizeof msg.payload, SERVER, 0) == -1) ...
```

Note the similarity in the calls to `msgsnd()` and `msgrcv()`.

Be aware of alignment restrictions, if you have any member in `struct payload` that has alignment restrictions larger than those of `gid`, it might cause `payload` to not follow immediately after `gid`. The `msgsz` parameter should take this into account. However, the above code should be fine.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks a lot. Had been stuck at this problem for a day.